# Packaged has been archived

Tags: flutter, datepicker, flutter-packages

I was using month_picker_dialog_2 for selecting months in my flutter app. But the owner of this package has archived this package. Is it reliable to use this package or else I should switch to some other package?

Are there any other packages with similar functionality?

Comment: Why not use https://pub.dev/packages/month_picker_dialog? The owner is working on it.